# Analyzing USB signals

Tags: usb, usb-device, logic-analyzer

I'm experimenting with HID lately. And I need to know more about the physical output signal of a USB keyboard. My goal in the end is to put a small data logger in between the USB-keyboard an a computer and capture all the signals which come through. Afterwards I want to try to decode the records again.
Once I accomplished this (if it is even possible) I want to do this with other USB Devices, such like web cam, mouse, maybe even printer... I know that it isn't easy with USB and I'm also a complete newbie to this topic. But I want to give it a try.

So in my first step I want to 'record' the physical signals with a logic analyzer and afterwards i want to replay the signal back to the host.
Do you think this is possible?

Comment: You can monitor all usb action from inside the PC. Look up a tool called BusDog. I am sure there are others

Comment: This is a rabbit hole that can prove to be too much effort. I'd recommend using a controller which already handles usb peripherals, or running an embedded linux. Going for bare-bones usb protocol is just not worth the sweat.

Comment: Yeah, don't even try to analyse what's going along the actual wires. USB is an extremely complex layered protocol and is completely driven by the host (the computer in this case). There's a mass of data going backwards and forwards even when nothing seems to be happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ready made USB analyzers that operate as a pass through device. In other words a device like your keyboard plugs into the analyzer and then a cable from the analyzer connects to the computer. The analyzer has yet another connection cable that goes to a data logging host computer that captures, analyzes and saves the data. In many cases the data logging host computer can simply be yet another USB port on the same computer that the keyboard connects to.

It hardly makes sense to attempt to build such device when it can simply be purchased. If your answer is that you want to learn then simply get yourself some USB port analyzer software for your computer. If you say that you want to build this as some type of product in quantity then I would question the usefulness of such product other than nefarious use which would be highly discouraged.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. So I got the idea from a hardware keylogger and i thought this can't be so hard... but how do keyloggers do it? they I don't think they need to work as a host to capture USB information, or do they?